# Why are PyYAML and ruamel.yaml escaping special characters when single quoted?

Tags: python-3.x, escaping, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file and would like to constrain a certain field to contain no whitespace.

Here's a script that demonstrates my attempt:

> ## test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
from ruamel import yaml

def read_conf(path_to_config):
    if os.path.exists(path_to_config):
        conf = open(path_to_config).read()
        return yaml.load(conf)
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    settings = read_conf("hello.yaml")
    print("type of name: {0}, repr of name: {1}".format(type(
             settings['foo']['name']), repr(settings['foo']['name'])))
    if any(c.isspace() for c in settings['foo']['name']):
        raise Exception("No whitespace allowed in name!")
```

Here is my first cut of the YAML file:

> ## hello.yaml

```
foo:
    name: "hello\t"
```

In the above YAML file, an exception is correctly raised:

```
type of name: <class 'str'>, repr of name: 'hello\t'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise Exception("No whitespace allowed in name!")
Exception: No whitespace allowed in name!
```

However, if I change the double quotes to single quotes, no exception is raised:

```
08:23 $ ./test.py 
type of name: <class 'str'>, repr of name: 'hello\\t'
```

This behavior occurs both when using `ruamel.yaml==0.11.11` and `PyYAML=3.11`.

Why is there a difference between single and double quotes in these Python YAML parsers when, as I understand it, there is no functional difference between them in YAML specs? How can I prevent special characters from being escaped?

Comment: What `yaml` module would be native to Python3? Neither `ruamel.yaml` nor  `PyYAML` are part of the standard python library.

Comment: @Anthon Oops. I had PyYAML installed globally and didn't realize it. :) Will edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a vast difference in the YAML specification between single and double quoted strings. Within [single quoted scalars](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097) you can only escape the single quote:

> The single-quoted style is specified by surrounding “'” indicators. Therefore, within a single-quoted scalar, such characters need to be repeated. This is the only form of escaping performed in single-quoted scalars.

Therefore `\` in  `'hello\t'` has no special function and that scalar consists of the letters `h`, `e`, `l` (2x), `o`. `\` and `t`

Backslash escaping is only supported in double quoted YAML scalars.

Comment: Ah, my understanding was buggy. :) I guess I'll need to broaden my constraint to preventing all special characters.

Comment: You can use tabs in in single quotes (and in literal and folded block scalars), but you have to  use the tab character itself, not the usual escape sequence (`\t`). Those characters then are, in many circumstances, difficult to distinguish from space(s), but that is correct YAML